# Why can't one calculate the energy of the one electron Uranium ion state with the Dirac equation?

Tags: atomic-physics, dirac-equation, elements

In the link, [Solving Dirac for one electron atom/ion](https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node501.html) the energy for the one electron
$s_1$ shell is calculated as
$$
E=m_{\mu}c^2\left( 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left( \frac{\alpha Z}{n-j-1/2 + \sqrt{(j+1/2)^2-\alpha^2 Z^2}} \right )^2}}\right).
$$

I am confused because if $Z=92$, then this is not computable for $j=0$ as $\alpha 92 > 1/2$ and then $ \sqrt{(j+1/2)^2-Z^2\alpha^2}$ is imaginary. Why's that? Is the formula in the link wrong?

Comment: The Klein Paradox: At Large $Z$  the vacuum is unstable to pair creation in which an electron from the filled Dirac sea can tunnel though the potential barrier and occupy  the energy lowest state.

Comment: @mikestone Perhaps but there is no such thing as a filled Dirac sea.

Comment: @ my2cts Why not?  It is convenient way to keep track, and as (these days) a condensed matter theorist it is how I have learned to think of things. The argument about infinite electric charge is misleading. In the standard model each generation has  $3\times 2/3 $ up quarks, $-3\times 1/3$ down quarks, and $-1$ electon-like particle, Net vacuum charge for each generation is zero.  There is nothing that the  filled sea gets wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, $j=0$ is impossible as $l=j\pm\frac{1}{2}$. Look at the definitions of $l$ and $j$.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, using this improves the values for other elements as well